# including konva.js 2D drawings in reveal.js slides using anything plugin

Tags: konvajs, reveal.js

I am new to reveal.js and have tried to include a konva.js 2D drawing to my slides. I modified the provided [sample codes](https://github.com/rajgoel/reveal.js-plugins/tree/master/anything) of anything plugin explaining how to include d3.js charts in slides to do that, but my work failed and nothing showed up in the expected convas element. I tried to repeat that work for chart.js charts and everything was fine. can anyone help me?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

        <title>reveal.js</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/reset.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/reveal.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/theme/white.css">

        <!-- Theme used for syntax highlighted code -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugin/highlight/monokai.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="reveal">
            <div class="slides">
                <section>Slide 1
                <div class="konva stretch" id="konva">
<!--
{
"initialize": "function(container) {
      var width = container.innerWidth;
      var height = container.innerHeight;

      container.stage = new Konva.Stage({
        container: container.id,
        width: width,
        height: height,
      });
      

      var layer = new Konva.Layer();

      var rect2 = new Konva.Rect({
        x: 10,
        y: 10,
        width: 300,
        height: 20,
        shadowBlur: 10,
        cornerRadius: 10,
        fillLinearGradientStartPoint: { x: -50, y: -20 },
        fillLinearGradientEndPoint: { x: -50, y: 20 },
        fillLinearGradientColorStops: [0, 'red', 1, 'yellow'],
      });
      layer.add(rect2);
      container.stage.add(layer);
  
 }"
}
-->
                </id>
                </section>
                <section>Slide 2</section>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="dist/reveal.js"></script>
        <script src="plugin/notes/notes.js"></script>
        <script src="plugin/markdown/markdown.js"></script>
        <script src="plugin/highlight/highlight.js"></script>
        <script src="plugin/anything/plugin.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@8.3.5/konva.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            // More info about initialization & config:
            // - https://revealjs.com/initialization/
            // - https://revealjs.com/config/
            Reveal.initialize({
                hash: true,

                // Learn about plugins: https://revealjs.com/plugins/
                plugins: [ RevealMarkdown, RevealHighlight, RevealNotes ],
                anything: [
                 {
                    className: "konva",  
                    initialize: (function(container, options){ if (options && options.initialize) { options.initialize(container)} })
                 },
                 // ...
                ],
                plugins: [ RevealAnything ],
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Edit:
I have realized that the DOM element I had used was a canvas but konva only accepts div. Now in chrome's inspect, I can see that the container is affected by the Konvajs but still nothing is shown up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the width and height of the div container that was zero. Changing

```
var width = container.innerWidth;
var height = container.innerHeight;
```

to something like:

```
var width = 400;
var height = 400;
```

solved the problem